# Converting argument $1 type: unsupported type []interface {}, a slice of interface

Tags: postgresql, go, pq

I try to query on list of userIDs. I am using the Go [Pq](https://github.com/lib/pq) library.

```
func ListUsers(userIDs []interface{}) (users []User, err error) {
    stm := `SELECT
    U.id,
    (
        CASE WHEN TRIM(UP.first_name || ' ' || UP.last_name) = '' THEN U.id :: TEXT ELSE UP.first_name || ' ' || UP.last_name END
        ) as avatar_name,
FROM
    users AS U
        JOIN user_profiles UP ON UP.user_id = U.id
WHERE
        U.id IN ($1);`

    rows, err := postgresql.Instance.Query(stm, userIDs)
    defer rows.Close()
    if err != nil && err != sql.ErrNoRows {
        return
    }

    if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
        return users, nil
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        var (
            id         int
            AvatarName string
        )
        err = rows.Scan(&id, &AvatarName)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        users = append(users, User{ID: id, AvatarName: AvatarName})
    }

    return users, nil
}
```

When I run this it gives error ***converting argument $1 type: unsupported type []interface {}, a slice of interface***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Wrap the slice with [pq.Array](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Array).
- Change `IN ($1)` to `= any($1)` so the array value can be used.

Here's the code:

```
    stm := `SELECT
    U.id,
    (
        CASE WHEN TRIM(UP.first_name || ' ' || UP.last_name) = '' THEN U.id :: TEXT ELSE UP.first_name || ' ' || UP.last_name END
        ) as avatar_name,
FROM
    users AS U
        JOIN user_profiles UP ON UP.user_id = U.id
WHERE
        U.id = any($1);`
    rows, err := postgresql.Instance.Query(stm, pq.Array(userIDs))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying to with IN what's wrong with that.